# VS Code Python Interactive Window ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am running a Python script in the VS Code Python Interactive Window with an Anaconda environment using Python 3.7.4). My "Notebook File Root" setting is set to $(workspaceFolder).

I am using a workspace with two project folders:

1. apple
2. connie

connie has a couple of files relevant in this problem:

connie/scripts/mongo_helpers.py

connie/project/project_file.py

The problem occurs when I run project_file.py in the Python Interactive Window. It tries to load the mongo_helpers file as a module.

```
from scripts import mongo_helpers
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\cygwin64\home\Robert\connie\project\project_file.py in 
----> 1 from scripts import mongo_helpers

ImportError: cannot import name 'mongo_helpers' from 'scripts' (C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\connie\lib\site-packages\scripts\__init__.py)
```

I print the working directory to see if I'm in the wrong folder, but it looks fine.

`pwd`

```
'c:\\cygwin64\\home\\Robert\\connie'
```

So why can't I import a file from another folder in the same root directory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been that the folder 'scripts' was not on the sys.path

See this article for details: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html

The following code solves the problem:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('scripts')
print(sys.path)
```

Now I can run `import mongo_helpers` to run the code in mongo_helpers.py