# VS Code relative import Python module "ImportError"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

0

I am using VS Code to code in Python. Every time I try to import a Python module from a relative path, there is the above error. There is nothing wrong with the folder path. I have tried the relative path import in Pycharm and it works fine.

However, if I click File -> Close folder and then reopen that folder, the error goes away and I am able to import from python modules. Why is this?

```
from py1 import hello
hello() # Simply should print "hello"


ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'py1'
```

The module `py1` is automatically intellisensed by the way, so there's nothing wrong with the file. I also have no problem with importing libraries.

Comment: Try to print [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) before import, it should help.

Comment: Tried it, not working. As I mentioned already if I reopen the folder everything is all good. Additionally I tried it out on Pycharm, no issue whatsoever. This might be a VScode bug or setting problem - there were others posting about it just no solution.

Comment: @ngong123 If it is convenient, could you provide the relevant folder directory information?  Try to add the file path,this link may help you: link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782772/vs-code-python-interactive-window-importerror-cannot-import-name  Also, check that the file is not renamed.